# How can a low level character help in a Guild Castle Seige?

Tags: runes-of-magic

I just joined a guild. I've done about 4 sieges with them; all I really do is stand at a tower collecting resources. This is easy enough, since I get killed in one shot by all the level 75 characters, but it sucks that the amount of resources I obtain is miniscule.

How can I be more helpful to my guild during a siege?

Answer (score 1):

low levels can go to 1 of the towers to the right or left of their castle, stand close to it and click it. You will start collecting merits and adding to the crystal count. The other players can trade with you and take your merits they use these to build defences. If you go to a site called Curse and download "Auto Trade" it makes it much easier to trade or collect later.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know (does not have to say anything, because i just did 2 sieges) you cannot do very much as low level. The rewards you get AFTER the siege is the only thing that is of interest for you on low level. If you really want to help (i.e. killing others) you have to grow.

Comment: As i've played this game, i've learned a lot more. I've found out a lot of how I can be more helpful. This answer is just lazy.

Comment: as i said, i have just done two ^^